# Magento 2.1 Admin panel isn't loading properly

Tags: admin-panel, navigation

It shows error we deploy command:

```
Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/css/source/module/components/navigation-bar/_navigation-bar.less
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy static view files specific for **admin area** only and with specific language:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --area adminhtml
```

Note: you can change the language as per your requirement.